# How to remove % character from url

Tags: urls, slug

I can't remove % characters from my url on wordpress website. There is no % character on my dashboard, but every time I try to copy my post url and into into google, FB or notepade I see a lot of %% sings like below. https://sorasadventures.com/%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%83/

Comment: Welcome! Can you update the question to indicate what you have tried to fix this?

Comment: If its only for copy paste you can add a `.` (dot) to the end of the url, that usualy helps. If thats not possible do a google search for `url decode online`, that will `clean` the url

Comment: What plugins do you have in your wordpress site? Is the site using a character encoding other than UTF-8 (for a language other than English for example)? This answer might help you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325676/why-wp-encodes-unicode-utf8-containing-urls-any-drawbacks-of-unicode-url